# Install latest kernel after /boot cleanup

Tags: boot, apt, kernel

I inherited a server with **Ubuntu 16.04** and a crazy uptime and `/boot` in a small separated partition with no space left. My installed kernels were:

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic       4.4.0-116.140                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic       4.4.0-119.143                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic       4.4.0-121.145                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic       4.4.0-124.148                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic       4.4.0-127.153                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic       4.4.0-128.154                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic       4.4.0-130.156                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic       4.4.0-133.159                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic       4.4.0-134.160                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic        4.4.0-21.37                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

being `linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic` my current kernel from `uname -r`

As seen, all installed kernels where newer than the currently installed, so I followed an answer in [Again… /boot is full [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976327/again-boot-is-full), but after runnig

```
dpkg --remove linux-image-4.4.0-{119,121,124,127,128,130,133}-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-{119,121,124,127,128,130,133}-generic
```

tried to run

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image-extra-generic
```

got this error

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-generic
```

`sudo apt-get autoremove` didn't work and suggests 'apt-get -f install'.

Afert doing an `apt-get -f install` tries to install again all previously deleted kernels:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-139 linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic linux-image-generic
```

How can I install only the newer kernel version without installing the ones in the middle?

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Suggest that you finish removing the kernels by also removing the related headers packages. Also purge the kernels you do not want, instead of just removing them.

Comment: I'm running 16.04