# increase boot partition size with encrypted disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption

my disk is encrypted, but boot partition is by default 512MB
how to increase boot partition?

also how to increase boot partition during fresh new install?

ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Why would you want to increase the size of `/boot`? Too many kernels installed? What's the output of `dpkg -l | grep -i linux-`?

Comment: apt update and apt update

Comment: i have to do apt auto remove all the time

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, sorry.

Comment: too long cant post 30k output

Comment: You can narrow it down with `dpkg -l | grep -i linux-image`

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/b0bc77fa

Comment: Houseclean kernels: https://askubuntu.com/questions/301466/files-are-piling-up-in-usr-src-how-can-i-stop-this & https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot & https://askubuntu.com/questions/976327/again-boot-is-full

Comment: @oldfred and when that is not enough? I've cleaned, still the size of boot is not enough for updates.