Extending boot partition using space from an encrypted partition
I need to increase the size of my boot partition because software updates require more space (deleting unused kernels and autoremove did not help).
My main partition is luks encrypted. It has about 100GB available space for files but no unallocated space as a partition.
What steps do I need to follow to increase the boot partition using disk space from the other encrypted partition? Frankly I'm afraid to cause damage.


This looks like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306247/increase-boot-partition-size-with-encrypted-disk. I added an answer there.
